# How to get JSON Data C# from stacked objects

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON object, which I've deserialized with C# into a variable using appropriate classes.

```
{"cmd": "test","cache": [{"cmd": "test","gw": [{"id": "123456"}],"data": "some_data"}]}
```

How can I get the value of "id" which is inside the "gw" object, which is inside "cache"?

Bellow are my classes for the deserialization.

```
public class Gw
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Cache
{
    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public List<Gw> gw { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public List<Cache> cache { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
object model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

If I try:

```
string myID = model.cache[0].gw[0].id;
string myID2 = model.cache.First().gw.First().id;
```

I get this message: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'cache' and no extension method 'cache' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
string myID = model.cache[0].gw[0].id;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: If I have multiple arrays in cache, how will I be able to count them?

Comment: You can use them just like any standard List, so you have the access to all of the fields and methods - for example the _model.cache.Count_ or _model.cache.gw.Count_ fields.  You might want to do a loop within a loop - foreach(var item in model.cache){ foreach(var itemGW in item.gw){ Console.WriteLine(itemGW.id); }}